# Git stash push with pathspec behavior

Tags: git

I don't understand the behavior of `git stash push` when used with its `pathspec` argument.

According to the documentation:

> When pathspec is given to git stash push, the new stash entry records the modified states only for the files that match the pathspec.

When working with changes in the staging area, after using `git stash push -- folder` everything inside `folder` disappears from the staging area as expected. But the stashed changes include not only what was in `folder` but also every other changes in the staging area.

```
root@96b24c3e98b4:/# git version
git version 2.27.0
root@96b24c3e98b4:/# git init tmp
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/.git/
root@96b24c3e98b4:/# cd tmp
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# mkdir folder
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# echo ok1 >folder/first.txt
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# echo ok1 >second.txt
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git add .
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git commit -m tmp
[master (root-commit) a3163c3] tmp
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 folder/first.txt
 create mode 100644 second.txt
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# echo ok2 >folder/first.txt
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# echo ok2 >second.txt
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git add .
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   folder/first.txt
    modified:   second.txt

root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git stash push -- folder
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: a3163c3 tmp
root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   second.txt

root@96b24c3e98b4:/tmp# git stash show -p
diff --git a/folder/first.txt b/folder/first.txt
index 28864ea..523b808 100644
--- a/folder/first.txt
+++ b/folder/first.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-ok1
+ok2
diff --git a/second.txt b/second.txt
index 28864ea..523b808 100644
--- a/second.txt
+++ b/second.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-ok1
+ok2
```

In that example why does `second.txt` end up in the stash entry?